# Simple composition of random variables.

Tags: probability, random-variables

If I have a (discrete) random variable $X$ defined as

\begin{equation}
X = \begin{cases}0 \qquad p_1=0.5\\
1 \qquad p_2=0.2 \\
2 \qquad p_3=0.3
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

If now I have $Y=2^X$ is it correct to write that

\begin{equation}
Y = \begin{cases}
1 \qquad p_1=0.5 \\
2 \qquad p_2=0.2 \\
4 \qquad p_3=0.3
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

and then calculating mean/variance etc.. thank you.

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Comment: How to compute cdf for this? I’d assume it would be $P(Y \le t) = P(2^X \le t) = P(X \le log_2(t)) but it wouldn’t be defined for some values of t (like zero)

Answer (score 2):

yes, to see why note that $\mathbb P_X(\{0\}) = \mathbb P(\{X^{-1}(0)\}) = \mathbb P(\{\omega\in\{0,1,2\}\mid \omega = 0\}) = 0.5$ by definition. Now what is $\mathbb P_Y(\{1\}) = \mathbb P(\{Y^{-1}(1)\}) = \mathbb P(\{\omega\in\{0,1,2\} \mid 2^\omega = 1\})$? Clearly, $\omega = 0$ is the only $\omega\in\{0,1,2\}$ such that $2^\omega = 1$. Thus, $\mathbb P_Y(\{1\}) = \mathbb P_X(\{0\})$.